# Matrix differentiation error

Tags: matrices

I was attempting to differentiate a problem using matrices but am running into some problems. Here's the problem setup. w and w_dot are both matrices that are depending on k. Differentiate the following with respect to k:

w_dot=inverse(J)*(cross(w,J*w)+Md+Mu+noise)

d[w_dot]/dk=d[inverse(J)*(cross(w,J*w)+Md+Mu+noise)]/dk

Since neither Md, Mu nor noise depend on k, and factoring inverse(J) out:

d[w_dot]/dk=inverse(J)*d[*(cross(w,J*w)]/dk

using the product rule:
d[w_dot]/dk=inverse(J)*(d[w]/dk*J*w+w*J*d[w]/dk)

for reference, here are the dimensions of the vectors:

J is a 3x3.
w and w_dot are 3x1.
Md and Mu and noise are 3x1.

Now you'll notice that the last line of my math contains w*J, which is (3x1)*(3x3), which is illegal matrix multiplication. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Hi, so k is just an independent variable, like time or something. It's sort of a discretized step

Comment: I thought I specified the dimensions of the matrices, above I say: J is a 3x3. w and w_dot are 3x1. Md and Mu and noise are 3x1.

Comment: if `cross` means cross product, then your product rule is wonky, as `cross` vanished in the differential.

Comment: What do you call cross?

Comment: cross(A,B) is the cross product of a and b

Comment: I think you understand the problem so feel free to write your answer a little more clearly and Ill accept it.

Comment: So what I wrote below is correct.

Comment: What you wrote below is not what I have, I have the same equation except on the right side I have no cross products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint.**

You have $$\frac{d}{dk}(w \times J.w)=(\frac{dw}{dk} \times (J.w)) + (w \times (J.\frac{dw}{dk}))$$

Comment: So I have multiplication instead of those cross products, so I'm confused by your wording.

Comment: It seems my cross product vanished in the differential.

Comment: With parenthesis!

Comment: yeah thanks but still you gotta take out the cross operators on the right I have multiplication

Comment: You answer is "the correct answer" but it ain't what i have above.